# Sharepoint API via REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I have created an "app" in sharepoint and have given xmlt rights to it.
I was trying to get the lists content from my sites but can't get it via http request because of Error 403.

Now im requesting a token via http oauth2 with this url:
http://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/MyTopSecretTenantId/tokens/Oauth/2/

This gives me an access_token back and i want to get the lists from my sharepoint API with this link:
https://3bac.sharepoint.com/sites/TestGroup/_api/web/list
Headers:
Content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Bearer: TheTokenFromTheFirstRequest

But it gives me back a 403: forbidden
"value": "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

This is the XML part I tried.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

It would be perfect to know how the XML has to look like to just read and write to items in lists.
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the list. I would recommend you to register app in the following link

> https://3bac.sharepoint.com/sites/TestGroup/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

And apply following xml in the link

> https://3bac.sharepoint.com/sites/TestGroup/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Here is a nice article for reference

https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/?expand_article=1